# How do I build a calculator in Javascript using Switch?

Tags: javascript, html

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
      <div id="calculator-container">
        <form name="calc">
          <!-- The name of the form is "calc" -->
          <label for="output">A Basic Calculator</label>
          <input id="output" name="output" type="text" readonly>

          <!-- the name of the textbox is "output" -->
          <br>
          <input type="button"   name="one"      value="  1  "    >
          <input type="button"   name="two"      value="  2  "    >
          <input type="button"   name="three"    value="  3  "    >
          <input type="button"   name="add"      value="  +  "    >
          <br>
          <input type="button"   name="four"     value="  4  "    >
          <input type="button"   name="five"     value="  5  "    >
          <input type="button"   name="six"      value="  6  "    >
          <input type="button"   name="subtract" value="  -  "    >
          <br>
          <input type="button"   name="seven"    value="  7  "    >
          <input type="button"   name="eight"    value="  8  "    >
          <input type="button"   name="nine"     value="  9  "    >
          <input type="button"   name="multiply" value="  x  "    >
          <br>
          <input type="button"   name="clear"    value="  C  "    >
          <input type="button"   name="zero"     value="  0  "    >
          <input type="button"   name="equate"   value="  =  "    >
          <input type="button"   name="divide"   value="&divide;" >
        </form>
      </div>
      <h2>Switch Version</h2>
    </div>
```

It goes on and everything else is set up correctly by the teacher. Can't post a picture unfortunately.

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var calcu = function(calcValue) {
    switch (calcValue) {
        case "one": 
            calc.output.value += 1;
            break;
        case "equate":
            // use the math.eval() function from the Math.js math library to parse and evaluate the String with mathematics in it
            calc.output.value = math.eval(calc.output.value);
            break;
    }
};
```

So according to my understanding, pressing '1' on the calculator should now display a 1 in the output form.

My teacher set up the function for us to use in the JS file and everything is linked correctly. I looked around for a bit and even at example JS calculator code but I don't know exactly what to ask or how to ask it. Hopefully someone can help. Thanks!

Comment: Help with **what** exactly?

Comment: you're missing a lot of code here, but to start with, `calc.output.value += 1; ` isn't going to do what you expect; you don't want to 'add' the value of the button pressed to the value, you want to 'append' it to the string, so the whole string can be evaluated at once.

Comment: I would let user write an arithmetic expression and then evaluate the whole thing in JavaScript :p

Comment: @LearnRailsFastandFree yes, but this is a homework assignment; the point of a homework assignment is that they do it the way it's requested, even if it's a longer way or an inefficient way, so that they get the experience of the concepts.

Comment: replace `math.eval` with just `eval` and all should be fine.

Comment: I would not do it this way at all either, but we have to use switch.

@claies I was guessing that. So would you recommend I put in ID in the HTML input tags? I realize I'm missing some code, I just can't figure out what I'm missing. lol.

before this, we had to do an inline version. So all the Javascript was inline in the HTML.

Comment: Clear mockery of the requirements, but why not `switch (true) { case true: /* sane calculator implementation */ }`

Comment: You don't need an ID, but the buttons do need an `onClick` to fire the function, and as I said earlier, you need to *append* the operator to the output, rather than *add* to it.

Comment: @Claies ok. So if I leave the in the JS function:
calc.output.value = 1; and then in the HTML input, add onclick"calcu()" it doesn't work, but am I getting closer?

Comment: this isn't exactly the format to use for extended discussions like this, but I'll try to point you a bit further.  the line for `calc.output.value += ` needs a *string* not a *number*, so instead of `1` it should be `'1'`.  Also, the function is expecting you to supply an argument in the `onClick` which is used to match the `case` in the `switch` statement.

Comment: @Claies Sorry, I've never used this site before. First time ever. Ok, I think that helps a lot, Thanks a lot!!

Comment: A big part of trying to answer homework questions is to try to point you in the right direction without just pasting code for you to turn in.  If we want good future co-workers, we have to help you understand how things work, not just hope you can find a copy of the answer.  This site tends to be more geared toward people who have specific concepts that are problematic, not really extended discussions.  It gets better once you have 20 reputation and can participate in the chat rooms, however.  Good luck in your learning!

Comment: I created a chat that we can use to discuss things a bit more http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70500/discussion-of-javascript-concepts

Answer (score 1):

So I have figured it out, thanks to @claies.

HTML:

```
<input type="button"   name="one"      value="  1  "   onclick="calcu(this.name)" >
```

JavaScript:

```
calc.output.value += "1";
```

Comment: you still want the `+=`, so that the second button gets added to the first, rather than just replacing the first.

Comment: I just realized. Where do I put that? I tried in both and one of each but it's not working. I can get the calculator to put a '1' in the form now, but it only works with adding on 1's for some reason

Comment: jump in the chat room I created http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70500/discussion-of-javascript-concepts